# MVC bind explicit properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model class with explicit properties and it seems MVC binder do not bind them. I get error

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary
```

Is this known issue? I can't find any documentation about this on google.

My class

```
 public interface IPdf2Source
    {
        string Password { get; set; }
        string OutputFormatSelected { get; set; }
    }

    public class OptionModel : IPdf2Source
    {

        public IPdf2Source Pdf2Source
        {
            get { return this; }
        }


        //Bind Ok
        public string Email { get; set; }


        //I get error on these properties while binding.
        string IPdf2Source.Password { get; set; }
        string IPdf2Source.OutputFormatSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Email)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Pdf2Source.Password)  
    @Html.HiddenFor(p=>p.Pdf2Source.OutputFormatSelected)
}
```

Controller Action which is never called because binding is failing. If I remove explicit declarated properties everything works fine.

```
public JsonResult ValidateFile(OptionModel formData)
{ 
}
```

Comment: Please show some code in your question so that we can better understand your issue.  Add as much code as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //I get error on these properties while binding.
    string IPdf2Source.Password { get; set; }
    string IPdf2Source.OutputFormatSelected { get; set; }
```

Why are those even in there? That is not proper syntax. Moreover, you already defined those values in the interface.

**Edit**

You are correct, sorry I was a little out of date on explicit interface definitions. It actually looks like you did almost everything perfectly, but now that I look at it I think I see your problem. It looks like you need to change your explicit definitions to `public`.

```
    public string IPdf2Source.Password { get; set; }
    public string IPdf2Source.OutputFormatSelected { get; set; }
```

Comment: Could you explain what is not properly here? This is explicit property declaration and I use this trick to group properties in class. Also if we have properties in interface we need them to implement in derived class.